# How to add new line in string variable

Tags: powerapps

I am trying to add array of string +value to other string variable along with new line('\n') in msflow.But that is not working. can any one please assist on this.

Here are the details:

1. Test-string-> string with some value(A)
2. Test-Array->Array of values["B","C"]

3.Test-Append->expecting result

AB

AC

current result

ABAC

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is tagged 'powerapps', but in the description you mention 'msflow' (Power Automate). Depending on which product you are talking about, you would approach it differently.

In Power Apps, you can use the function [Char(10)](https://learn.microsoft.com/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/functions/function-char) to add a new line to a string. So if you have a string variable and a collection with values, you can use something like the expression below:

```
Set(testString, "A");
Collect(testArray, "B", "C");
Set(result, Concat(testArray, testString & Value & Char(10)))
```

In Power Automate, it's not as simple, but I've found one alternative at [this community post](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Flows/How-can-you-enter-a-Newline-into-a-string/td-p/102447) where you can use the expression below to have a new line character:

```
json('{"NL":"\n"}')?['NL']
```

So if you have your variables initialized as below:

[image: Power Automate - variable initialization]

You can append the new line inside an Apply to each block:

[image: Appending new line to each item in the array]

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

It depends on where the output is to be.

e.g. if the concatenated text is to be sent in an email, then then new line character is `<br/>`.

Hence this is why flow didn't provide a native expression for it.